# the column 'id' is not the primary_key ,how to reset the Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table form the second database,it is not through a migration

```
class Dzhfeed < Dzxdb

  set_table_name "pre_home_feed"

  set_primary_key :feedid

end
```

the table:

```
CREATE TABLE pre_home_feed (
  feedid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  appid smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' ,
  icon varchar(30) NOT NULL default '' ',
  uid mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' ,
  username varchar(15) NOT NULL default '' ',
  dateline int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' ,
  friend tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  hash_template varchar(32) NOT NULL default '' ,
  hash_data varchar(32) NOT NULL default '' ,
  title_template text NOT NULL,
  title_data text NOT NULL,
  body_template text NOT NULL ,
  body_data text NOT NULL,
  body_general text NOT NULL ,
  image_1 varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' ,
  image_1_link varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  image_2 varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' ,
  image_2_link varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' ,
  image_3 varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' ,
  image_3_link varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' ,
  image_4 varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' ,
  image_4_link varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' ,
  target_ids text NOT NULL ,
  id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' ,
  idtype varchar(15) NOT NULL default '' ,
  hot mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY  (feedid),
  KEY uid (uid,dateline),
  KEY dateline (dateline),
  KEY hot (hot),
  KEY id (id,idtype)
) ;
```

but this table has another column named 'id' and not a primary_key

so ,when i want to create a new Dzhfeed ,I don't know how to set the column named id

my code is

```
feed = Dzhfeed.new(:appid => 0, :icon => 'doing', :uid => 1, :username => 'admin', :title_template => "xxxxxxxxxx", :body_template => '', :dateline => Time.now, :id => 0)
```

but it not work 
the error is

```
Mysql::Error: Column 'id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `pre_home_feed` (`image_3`, `uid`, `id`, `dateline`, `title_template`, `idtype`, `image_1`, `username`, `body_template`, `image_1_link`, `image_3_link`, `friend`, `title_data`, `appid`, `body_data`, `image_2_link`, `hot`, `image_4_link`, `image_4`, `hash_template`, `body_general`, `icon`, `target_ids`, `hash_data`, `image_2`) VALUES ('', 1, NULL, 1304675043, 'xxxxxxxxxx', '', '', 'admin', '', '', '', 0, '', 0, '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', 'doing', '', '', '')
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the question updates.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the table "pre_home_feed". If it is through a migration, it would have added a `id` column by default and set it as a primary key. In order not to add a 'id' column you have to say `:id => false, :force => true` in your table definition migration file and re-run the migration. ( Re-running a migration would first require a rollback, `rake db:rollback`. This command will undo the last migration run. )

The way you're setting the primary key is perfectly fine. You go about creating the objects in the standard way like this;

```
@feed = Dzhfeed.new( :feedid => :value .. )
```

I suggest you go through the [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/).

**Update:**

Linking to a two different databases is a little different. Essentially, you need to use the [establish_connection](http://syedaslam.com/2011/01/18/connecting-two-databases) method defined in [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-establish_connection) to do that:

```
establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "postgresql",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "username",
  :password => "password",
  :database => "database_to_link_to"
)
```

**Update:**

According to [this post here](http://roninonrails.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-non-standard-primary-keys-with.html) your problem should be solved using [composite_primary_keys](https://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys) gem.

Essentially what you need to do is this:

Install the gem composite_primary_keys, and then

```
require 'composite_primary_keys'
class Dzhfeed < Dzxdb
  set_primary_keys :feedif    
end
```

Notice, it is `set_primary_keys` and not `set_primary_key`. This should solve your problem.